# Windows 10 blender blackscreen, no cursor, no USB power

Tags: rendering, windows

I get a black screen after working a few minutes on blender with the Cycle render method active.
Most of the time I have a second window of blender open, set to a camera with Viewport Shading on.
Until today there weren't any problems with that.

Now, like I said, I get a blackscreen after a few minutes without error message etc. and on top of that the USB power goes out on the computer, it would still be on but
none of my display show anything and I can't do any shortcuts. The USB back- and frontports are affected by that. So I have to force shutdown the computer.

I only get this kind of phenomenon with blender.
Here is what I tried:

Working without the cycle render window, everything works just dandy. No blackscreen, no errors, nothing.
I reinstalled blender multiple times, on different drives (C:/D:). I used 2.91, installed 2.83, installed the Steam version, on all versions the same behaviour.
I reinstalled my graphics card driver with Geforce Experience and over the device-manager, even completely reinstalled my whole Windows system. Same issue.
The event viewer doesn't give me any info I can work with and no further error messages are displayed after a restart.
I can run a GPU benchmark and bring the GPU to 100% for a prolonged time without any problems.

My specs:
OS:     Windows 10 Home
Version:    10.0.19042 Build 19042
CPU:        AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-Core Processor
GPU:        NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
Motherboard:    PRIME X370-PRO
Version:    Rev X.0x

If there are any missing infos, please tell me and I will try to provide them.

Comment: Update your gpu driver, flickering, intermittent black screen is display driver problem.

Comment: I think GeForce Experience installed the newest drivers, after manually checking I can assure that the newest drivers are installed. 
The screen doesn't flicker black and goes back to normal, it just stays black even after waiting a few minutes

Comment: developer.blender.org to report this, it is a bug.

Comment: Maybe you should try the studio drivers instead of game drivers if you haven't already.

Comment: Same issue with the studio drivers

Comment: Disabled USB devices sounds like some sort of hardware issue, no software should normally do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually flashing the BIOS and installing a newer build with a flash drive did the trick.